# Preserve TextField value on orientation change in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

I have a `TextField` inside an `OrientationBuilder` in Flutter.

Now what happens, when I change the orientation of my App, is that the current value of the TextField (e.g. the text the user has put into into it) is lost, but I want to preserve the value of the TextField.

I need to rebuild the `TextField`, because the layout is different in landscape mode.

Can this be done?

EDIT:

This is what I have tried so far:

Both times I used the following model (located at -> models -> markdownModel.dart):

```
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';

class Code extends Model{
  String _markdown = '# Markdown Preview \n Your Markdown will be rendered here, once you start typing in the editor pane.';

  String get markdown => _markdown;


  void changeMarkdown(String markdown){
    this._markdown = markdown;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Now on my first try I did the following (however note, that the value of the TextField is not preserved on OrientationChange):

```
import 'package:flutter_markdown/flutter_markdown.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';
import 'models/markdownModel.dart';

void main() => runApp(HomeScreen(
      markdown: Code(),
    ));

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final Code markdown;

  const HomeScreen({Key key, this.markdown}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScopedModel<Code>(
      model: markdown,
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: OrientationBuilder(
          builder: (context, orientation) {
            return orientation == Orientation.portrait
                ? DefaultTabController(
                    initialIndex: 1,
                    length: 2,
                    child: Scaffold(
                      appBar: AppBar(
                        bottom: TabBar(
                          tabs: <Widget>[
                            Tab(text: "Editor", /*icon: Icon(Icons.edit),*/),
                            Tab(text:"Preview", /*icon: Icon(Icons.chrome_reader_mode),*/),
                          ],
                        ),
                        title: Text("Markdown - Editor"),
                        centerTitle: true,
                      ),
                      body: TabBarView(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          TextEditorWidget(),
                          MarkdownPreviewWidget()
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                : Scaffold(
                    appBar: AppBar(
                      title: Text("Markdown - Editor"),
                      centerTitle: true,
                    ),
                    body: Container(
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(
                            child: TextEditorWidget(),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: MarkdownPreviewWidget(),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TextEditorWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  TextEditorWidget({Key key,}) : super(key: key,);

  @override
  _TextEditorWidgetState createState() => _TextEditorWidgetState();
}

class _TextEditorWidgetState extends State<TextEditorWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScopedModelDescendant<Code>(builder: (context, child, model) {
      return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
        child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
              minWidth: 30, maxWidth: 40, minHeight: 50, maxHeight: 1400),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            reverse: true,
            child: TextField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
              onChanged: (text){
                model.changeMarkdown(text);
              },
              maxLines: null,
              decoration:
                  InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: "Write Markdown here."),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}

class MarkdownPreviewWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MarkdownPreviewWidget({Key key,}) : super(key: key,);

  @override
  _MarkdownPreviewWidgetState createState() => _MarkdownPreviewWidgetState();
}

class _MarkdownPreviewWidgetState extends State<MarkdownPreviewWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScopedModelDescendant<Code>(builder: (context, child, model) {
      return Container(
        child: new Markdown(
          data: model.markdown,
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

And then I used a `TextEditingController` outside the build method of my `OrientationBuilder` as pointed out by George. This works (with a bit of additional fiddeling in my case), however the Application is now incredibly slow:

```
import 'package:flutter_markdown/flutter_markdown.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';
import 'models/markdownModel.dart';

void main() => runApp(HomeScreen(
      markdown: Code(),
    ));

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final Code markdown;

  const HomeScreen({Key key, this.markdown}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScopedModel<Code>(
      model: markdown,
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: MainView(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MainView extends StatefulWidget {
  MainView({Key key,}) : super(key: key,);

  @override
  _MainViewState createState() => _MainViewState();
}

class _MainViewState extends State<MainView> {
  final _textController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the Widget is removed from the Widget tree
    // This also removes the _printLatestValue listener
    _textController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OrientationBuilder(
          builder: (context, orientation) {
            return orientation == Orientation.portrait
                ? DefaultTabController(
                    initialIndex: 1,
                    length: 2,
                    child: Scaffold(
                      appBar: AppBar(
                        bottom: TabBar(
                          tabs: <Widget>[
                            Tab(text: "Editor", /*icon: Icon(Icons.edit),*/),
                            Tab(text:"Preview", /*icon: Icon(Icons.chrome_reader_mode),*/),
                          ],
                        ),
                        title: Text("Markdown - Editor"),
                        centerTitle: true,
                      ),
                      body: TabBarView(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          TextEditorWidget(textController: _textController,),
                          MarkdownPreviewWidget()
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                : Scaffold(
                    appBar: AppBar(
                      title: Text("Markdown - Editor"),
                      centerTitle: true,
                    ),
                    body: Container(
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(
                            child: TextEditorWidget(textController: _textController,),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: MarkdownPreviewWidget(),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
          });
  }
}


class TextEditorWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final textController;
  TextEditorWidget({Key key, @required this.textController }) : super(key: key,);

  @override
  _TextEditorWidgetState createState() => _TextEditorWidgetState();
}

class _TextEditorWidgetState extends State<TextEditorWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScopedModelDescendant<Code>(builder: (context, child, model) {
      widget.textController.addListener(
        model.changeMarkdown(widget.textController.text)
      );
      return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
        child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
              minWidth: 30, maxWidth: 40, minHeight: 50, maxHeight: 1400),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            reverse: true,
            child: TextField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
              controller: widget.textController,
              maxLines: null,
              decoration:
                  InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: "Write Markdown here."),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}

class MarkdownPreviewWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MarkdownPreviewWidget({Key key,}) : super(key: key,);

  @override
  _MarkdownPreviewWidgetState createState() => _MarkdownPreviewWidgetState();
}

class _MarkdownPreviewWidgetState extends State<MarkdownPreviewWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScopedModelDescendant<Code>(builder: (context, child, model) {
      return Container(
        child: new Markdown(
          data: model.markdown,
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

EDIT 2:

I think the above example is slow, because the following exception is thrown over and over:

```
I/flutter ( 5375): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FOUNDATION LIBRARY 

╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 5375): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while dispatching notifications for
I/flutter ( 5375): TextEditingController:
I/flutter ( 5375): The method 'call' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 5375): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 5375): Tried calling: call()
I/flutter ( 5375):
I/flutter ( 5375): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 5375): #0      Object.noSuchMethod  (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:50:5)
I/flutter ( 5375): #1      ChangeNotifier.notifyListeners 
package:flutter/…/foundation/change_notifier.dart:206
I/flutter ( 5375): #2      ValueNotifier.value= 
package:flutter/…/foundation/change_notifier.dart:270
I/flutter ( 5375): #3      TextEditingController.selection= 
package:flutter/…/widgets/editable_text.dart:166
I/flutter ( 5375): #4      EditableTextState._handleSelectionChanged 
package:flutter/…/widgets/editable_text.dart:1118
I/flutter ( 5375): #5      RenderEditable.selectPositionAt 
package:flutter/…/rendering/editable.dart:1403
I/flutter ( 5375): #6      RenderEditable.selectPosition 
package:flutter/…/rendering/editable.dart:1375
I/flutter ( 5375): #7      _TextFieldState._handleSingleTapUp 
package:flutter/…/material/text_field.dart:686
I/flutter ( 5375): #8      _TextSelectionGestureDetectorState._handleTapUp 
package:flutter/…/widgets/text_selection.dart:806
I/flutter ( 5375): #9      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp.<anonymous closure> 
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:238
I/flutter ( 5375): #10     GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback 
package:flutter/…/gestures/recognizer.dart:166
I/flutter ( 5375): #11     TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp 
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:238
I/flutter ( 5375): #12     TapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture 
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:211
I/flutter ( 5375): #13     GestureArenaManager.sweep 
package:flutter/…/gestures/arena.dart:156
I/flutter ( 5375): #14     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:225
I/flutter ( 5375): #15     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:199
I/flutter ( 5375): #16     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:156
I/flutter ( 5375): #17     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:102
I/flutter ( 5375): #18     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:86
I/flutter ( 5375): #22     _invoke1  (dart:ui/hooks.dart:233:10)
I/flutter ( 5375): #23     _dispatchPointerDataPacket  (dart:ui/hooks.dart:154:5)
I/flutter ( 5375): (elided 3 frames from package dart:async)
I/flutter ( 5375):
I/flutter ( 5375): The TextEditingController sending notification was:
I/flutter ( 5375):   TextEditingController#05f71(TextEditingValue(text: ┤├, selection: TextSelection(baseOffset: 0,
I/flutter ( 5375):   extentOffset: 0, affinity: TextAffinity.downstream, isDirectional: false), composing:
I/flutter ( 5375):   TextRange(start: -1, end: -1)))
I/flutter ( 5375): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 5375): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'call' was called on null.
I/chatty  ( 5375): uid=10098(com.example.markdown_editor) Thread-2 identical 42 lines
I/flutter ( 5375): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'call' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 5375): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'call' was called on null.
I/chatty  ( 5375): uid=10098(com.example.markdown_editor) Thread-2 identical 7 lines
```

Btw. I am trying to build a simple markdown editor with live preview...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why this happens:** `OrientationBuilder` rebuilds itself on orientation change, possibly resetting the state of all the widgets inside of it.

**Solution:** Assign a `TextEditingController` to your `TextField`, with the controller being declared outside of `OrientationBuilder` context. This will prevent the textfield from losing its value.

e.g.

```dart
final _controller = TextEditingController();

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // ...
    TextField(
      controller: _controller,
    )
  // ...
}
```

---

**EDIT** thanks for the included code.

First of, change this:

```dart
class _TextEditorWidgetState extends State<TextEditorWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScopedModelDescendant<Code>(builder: (context, child, model) {
      widget.textController.addListener(
        model.changeMarkdown(widget.textController.text)
      );
// ...
```

to this:

```dart
class _TextEditorWidgetState extends State<TextEditorWidget> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.textController.addListener(controllerListener);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.textController.removeListener(controllerListener);
    super.dispose();
  }

  void controllerListener() {
    // I'm not entirely sure what `changeMarkdown` method does exactly in your code.
    // If this does not work - ask a separate question about scoped models.
    ScopedModel.of<Code>(context).changeMarkdown(widget.textController.text);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScopedModelDescendant<Code>(builder: (context, child, model) {

  // ...
}
```

Also, one minor thing - in `Row` consider replacing `Expanded` with `Flexible`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This answers my question, however as I by mistake forgot to point out, is that I already use a TextEditingController together with a scopedModel. So this is not really an option for me, I have still tried, but I think I will have to start a new question with a more in depth explanation of my problem.

Comment: It is best to include some code at all times. If you already use a controller that you can't discard, another solution could be building a parent<->child bind between controllers by adding a listener to the parent controller and using it's value for the child.

Comment: I included my code, it is not a minimal example, because I did not really know, how I should boil down my code, as this would have omitted part of the problem...

Comment: ok please see the edited answer. Listeners should be assigned on state init & disposed on state dispose. In `build` method it is only widgets that are supposed to be, well, built. I recommend to ask a separate question about scoped models if this does not help. But also I do feel like the idea that you are building can be achieved in a much simpler way - without scoped models etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It now works perfectly. Yes, I think when I would have used for example a `.txt` file to store my text in, it would have been much simpler...

Answer (score 2):

Sorry For Late Answer @George way is correct but easy way is to implement this by using Keys in widget just add key field in `TextField` widget and add     `final _inputKey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'inputText');`in State Class it will preserve text field value on orientation change